# Polarion WorkItem class getter methods returning null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am attempting to write a Java program that gets work record information off of Polarion and writes it to a DAT file for later use.

I have successfully connected to our servers and have retrieved the `WorkItem` objects, but none of the getter methods (besides `getUri()`) seem to work, which poses a problem since I need to use the `WorkItem` class's `getWorkRecords()` method to satisfy the requirements of the project.

I have tried all of the getter methods for the class on both our main Polarion server and our 'staging' server, which we use as a kind of testing area for things such as the program I am trying to write and on which I have full permissions.

Regardless of permissions, I am only querying for some dummy workitems I created and assigned to myself, so there shouldn't be any permissions issues since I am only attempting to view my own workitems.

Here is the code for the program:

```
package test;
//stg= 10.4.1.50
//main= 10.4.1.10


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;

import com.polarion.alm.ws.client.WebServiceFactory;
import com.polarion.alm.ws.client.session.SessionWebService;
import com.polarion.alm.ws.client.tracker.TrackerWebService;
import com.polarion.alm.ws.client.types.tracker.WorkItem;
import com.polarion.alm.ws.client.types.tracker.WorkRecord;


public class WorkrecordImporter {

private WebServiceFactory factory;
private TrackerWebService trackerService;
private SessionWebService sessionService;
private WorkItem[] workItems;
private ArrayList<WorkRecord> workRecords;
private String password = //insertpasswordhere;//no peaking

public WorkrecordImporter()throws ServiceException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{

    initializeFields();//initializes all of the Web Services and arrays
    //step one
    getWorkItems();
    //readDATFile();
    //step two
    getWorkRecords();
    //$$$
    printWorkRecords();
    //$$$$$
    writeDATFile();

}
//you know what this does.
public void printWorkRecords(){
    for(int temp = 0; temp < workItems.length; temp++){

        System.out.println(workItems[temp].getUri().toString());
    }
}
public void writeDATFile() throws IOException{
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\sweidenkopf\\workspace\\test\\filename.dat"));
    try {
        out.writeObject(workRecords);
    } finally {
        // Make sure to close the file when done
        out.close();
    }
}
/**
 * This method sets up the WebServiceFactory at the specified URL. It then initializes the web services, logs in the 
 * session service, and initializes the arrays. 
 * @throws MalformedURLException
 * @throws ServiceException
 * @throws RemoteException
 */
public void initializeFields() throws MalformedURLException, ServiceException, RemoteException{
    factory = new WebServiceFactory("//insert url here");
    trackerService = factory.getTrackerService();
    sessionService = factory.getSessionService();
    sessionService.logIn("sweidenkopf", password);
    workRecords = new ArrayList<>();
}
public void getWorkItems()throws MalformedURLException, ServiceException, RemoteException{
    sessionService.beginTransaction();
    workItems = trackerService.queryWorkItems("workRecords.user.id:sweidenkopf", null, null);
    sessionService.endTransaction(false);
}
public void getWorkRecords()throws MalformedURLException, ServiceException, RemoteException{
    sessionService.beginTransaction();
    for(int k = 0; k < workItems.length; k++)
    {System.out.println("This is working");
        try{//not every work item has work records
            System.out.println(workItems[k].getWorkRecords());
            WorkRecord[] temp;
            temp = workItems[k].getWorkRecords();
            for(int x = 0; x < temp.length; x++){
                System.out.println("This is working fine");
                workRecords.add(temp[x]);                   
            }
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("I must regretfully inform you that I have grave news; your endeavors have not been successfull.");
            continue;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(workRecords.toString());
    sessionService.endTransaction(false);
}
public void readDATFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\sweidenkopf\\workspace\\test\\filename.dat"));

    try{
        Object temp = in.readObject();
        workRecords = (ArrayList) temp;
    }
    finally{
        in.close();
    }
}
}
```

The most important part is of course the `getWorkRecords()` method within **my code**. As you can see, it contains the statement `System.out.println(workItems[k].getWorkRecords());` that I am using for debugging purposes. This statement returns `null`, and the only `WorkItem` method that does not return null when substituted in that statement is `getUri()`. Also, the try-catch block in that method always catches a `NullPointerException` because of the `for` loop contains `temp.length`, temp being a variable that should contain the return of the `getWorkRecords()` method.

**To summarize** the main issue here is that I am unable to return anything from `getWorkRecords()` or any other getter methods from the `WorkItem` class. This is puzzling because the `getUri()` method is executing successfully, as the `printWorkRecords()` method from my code successfully prints the URIs of all of the `WorkItem` objects erturn from my query.

Are there any Polarion experts that have encountered this issue before? Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am inclined to think it is a bug based on the circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at my calling of the `queryWorkItems()` method, you will notice that after the query parameter I specify two null parameters. The first specifies how you want the returned work items sorted (which is inconsequential at the moment), but the second is a `String` array called `fields` that is used to specify which of the `WorkItem` fields you want returned along with the `WorkItems` themselves. Apparently, if you set that to `null` like I did, it defaults to only returning the URI. For other things, like author, workrecord, and type, you have to place them in the `String` array and and pass that array when you call the method.